# Disable future dates in angular-datepicker in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-daterangepicker

I am facing issue with disabling date in angular-datepicker.
This is how I have defined datepicker:-

```
<datepicker date-format="{{pattern}}" 
            button-prev="<i class='fa fa-arrow-left' ></i>" 
            button-next="<i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i>">
  <input class="form-control ng-valid ng-valid-number ng-valid-max ng-valid-min ng-dirty ng-pristine" 
         name="pointAllocDate" type="text" 
         placeholder="Select Date*" id="pointAllocDate" required="required" 
         autocomplete="off" />
</datepicker>
```

I have defined pattern in angularjs controller as

```
$scope.pattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss';
```

Linked the css and js for datepicker as follows:-

```
<link href="css/angular-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/js/angular-datepicker.js"></script>
```

I am not getting how to disable future dates in this datepicker.Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `date-max-limit="today"` in the datepicker.

In the variable `today`, set today's date. It will set the maximum date as today and will disable the future dates.
For more reference visit this: https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker/blob/master/README.md